# call a class and display the results

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-intent

I am new at android eclipse , i created a class that finds the max number as follows

```
public class find_max_alg {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

 int data[] = {4,6,-5,5,8};

    int largest=data[0];
 for(int x=0; x<data.length; x++){
 if(data[x]>largest){
 largest = data[x];
 }
```

i need to call this class from a button in android and show the results in a display filed under the button can anybody help me on that or show me from where to start.thanks

Comment: If you have checked and tries my given solution that please accept my solution.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need a class for that. Create this as a function in the same Activity where the button is residing.

In case you want to access this from multiple activities, you need to create a static method in a separate class. Main is not required in Android.

Answer (score 0):

First Create this Activity.

```
package com.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn_cal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cal);
        btn_cal.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int result = MyCalculations.find_max_alg();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Then, create this class called "MyCalculations" for the same package.

```
package com.test;

public class MyCalculations {

    public static int find_max_alg() {
        int data[] = { 4, 6, -5, 5, 8 };

        int largest = data[0];
        for (int x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
            if (data[x] > largest) {
                largest = data[x];
            }
        }
        return largest;
    }

}
```

This will do all your job. On click of button you will have largest value in the toast message.

Thanks.